# Need to display certain categories by ID using this code woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code but it displays all categories which had products added to it. I only need to display certain categories by ID using this code below.

```
<span class="top"><h2>TOP CATEGORIES</h2></span>

<?php
    $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1
    ));
    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
?>

    <div class="catimg">
        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" />
        </a>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'include' => array(IDs HERE),
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 1
));
```